# Rostest arguments in CMakeLists

Tags: catkin, rostest, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to hand arguments to a test script which I can do with a regular call:

```
rostest package_name testlaunchfile.test argument1:=vaule1 argument2:=value2
```

But what do I do in CMakeLists:

```
add_rostest(test/testlaunchfile.test argument1:=vaule1 argument2:=value2)
```

I realize that it wount be working like this because the arguments are interpreted as source files. 
*But what can I do?*

### Edit: What I tried before:

I was giving the arguments to the launchfile via env vars. which seems to not work either. when i set them manually, it works. but catkin seems to fail setting them correctly. **Any Ideas on that?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174807/rostest-arguments-in-cmakelists/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can pass arbitrary arguments to rostest using the `ARGS` KEYWORD, e.g.

```
add_rostest(test/testlaunchfile.test ARGS argument1:=vaule1 argument2:=value2)
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-24**:
Thank you! This is really helpful. But could I have found this out by miself? I am just asking whether I am missing out on a great ressource or unable to google any more. ;)

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-06-24**:
This is the third result for `rostest arguments`: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/232 which I see you've already found.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-24**:
I tested it - it is actually working. YEAH!! Thank you so much :D I was already going crazy for a bit .. ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't need to pass in arguments from the `CMakeLists.txt` like that. If `test/testlaunchfile.test` requires arguments you should wrap it in another `.test` file which includes it and sets the arguments.

```
<launch>
  <include file="$(find package_name)/test/testlaunchfile.test">
    <arg name="argument1" value="value1" />
    <arg name="argument2" value="value2" />
  </include>
</launch>
```

EDIT: @Dirk Thomas's answers is better.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-06-24**:
Thanks for your answer. My Problem is that i decide at compile time what i want to test and due to that i have to pass arguments to the test script.